# How to handle request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with requests in node js. All time i get 404 error.

router:

```
router.get('/within', function (req, res){
    var lat1 = parseFloat(req.query.lat1);
    var lon1 = parseFloat(req.query.lon1);
    var lat2 = parseFloat(req.query.lat2);
    var lon2 = parseFloat(req.query.lon2);
    var db = req.db;

    db.collection('parks').find({"pos" : { $geoWithin : { $box: [[lon2,lat2], [lon1,lat1]]}}}).toArray(function(err,names){
        res.header("Content-Type:","application/json");
        res.end(JSON.stringify(names));
    });
});
```

And request url:

```
http://localhost:3012/within?lat1=77.31251993823143&lon1=139.92187500000003&lat2=-44.59046718130884&lon2=-190.54687500000003
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: "The HTTP 404 Not Found Error means that the webpage you were trying to reach could not be found on the server". make sure you are reaching `router.get('/within',` function

Comment: I don't think you've shown enough code to narrow down where you've gone wrong - for instance ... what is `router` - I could guess, but as you've only tagged your question javascript/node.js it would only be a guess (that you are using express.js)

Comment: One issue I can see is that your `content-type:` header would result in  `500 internal error` response ... therefore, your get request isn't even hitting that code (which is obvious) - so the problem lies somewhere outside of the code you've shared

Comment: Nothing wrong in the snippet you have shown. Error is somewhere else. You need to show more code.

Comment: I just don't understand. I got router what gonna work with url. In browser i go to `http://localhost:3012/within` and got `404 (Not Found)`. What more code i gonna have? Im new with node so my questions may be little stupid.

Answer (score -2):

Check three points: 
Your server is running on 3012?
you have included router file where this code is written?
your server is working ?